# Bash script to update text between tags in a pom file?

Tags: regex, sed, pom.xml

I've googled this but can't find a specific answer.

I have a pom.xml file with the following tags

```
<properties>
    <rpm.release>10</rpm.release>
</properties>
```

I then have toe following script that looks for the  tag between the  tag, which works.

```
update_rpm_release_in_pom()
{
  BUILD_NUM=$1
  POM_FILE="./template/iptools/pom.xml"
  BEGIN_PROPERTIES="n"
  # Look for the <rpm.release> tag in the <properties>
  # and update with with passed-in build_num
  cat $POM_FILE | while read LINE
  do
    case $BEGIN_PROPERTIES in
      n) # <property> tag not found yet
        if [[ "$LINE" == *\<properties\>* ]]; then
          BEGIN_PROPERTIES="y"
        fi
        continue
      ;;
      y) # <property> tag found
        if [[ "$LINE" == *\</properties\>* ]]; then
          # </property> tag found, stop searching
          break
        fi
        if [[ "$LINE" == *rpm.release* ]]; then
          # Update value
          ####################################
          # How do I update value??????
          ####################################
          break
        fi
      ;;
    esac
  done
}

# Call above function    
update_rpm_release_in_pom 11
```

What should I put in the "# How do I update value???" so when I run the script, pom.xml now has

```
<properties>
    <rpm.release>11</rpm.release>
</properties>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose, with the usual caveats about regex and XML, you could do this with regex. Fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the caveats, but I believe my case is simple that I can live with them. I'm not a regex expert.

Comment: Do you need to increment the version number or just set it to a hardcoded value?

Comment: I need to set it to the passed-in value stored in local variable $BUILD_NUM.

Comment: `perl -pi -e 's/<rpm.release>10<\/rpm.release>/<rpm.release>11<\/rpm.release>/g'`, Not bash but should do the trick.

Comment: "Not bash" is NOT what I need though, but thanks! Also, your example hardcodes values 10 & 11, but those values can be any number.

Comment: @ChrisF, why is "not bash" not the answer? You tagged the question with [tag:sed].

Comment: Boris provided a perl answer, and he said "Not bash but..." A "Not bash but...." answer is not what I needed.

Comment: Why don't you do this in python and invoke your python script from the bash file. Would be cleaner and more sustainable.

Comment: I have reasons to do it in bash. If python was an option, I would've already done it and not posted the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question was tagged [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), I suppose `awk` would be a valid alternative.

In this case you could process the pom file in `awk`, save the result in a tmpfile and overwrite the original file with the modified version:

```
#!/bin/sh

# error function
error(){
 echo -e >&2 "error: $@"
 exit 1
}

update_rpm_release_in_pom()
{
  #################
  # set constants #
  #################

  POM_FILE="./template/iptools/pom.xml"
  USAGE="usage: update_rpm_release_in_pom <build num>"

  #################
  # sanity checks #
  #################

  # argument given?
  [[ $# -eq 1 ]] || \
    error "wrong number of parameters\n$USAGE"

  # pom file exists?
  [[ -e "$POM_FILE" ]] || \
    error "pom file $POM_FILE does not exist"

  # pom file readable?
  [[ -r "$POM_FILE" ]] || \
    error "pom file $POM_FILE is not readable"

  # pom file writeable?
  [[ -w "$POM_FILE" ]] || \
    error "pom file $POM_FILE is not writeable"

  ##################
  # set parameters #
  ##################

  BUILD_NUM=$1

  ###############################
  # create temporal output file #
  # and ensure its removal      #
  ###############################

  # cleanup function
  cleanup(){
    [[ -e "$TMP_FILE" ]] && rm -- "$TMP_FILE"
  }

  # ensure cleanup on exit
  trap 'cleanup' EXIT

  # create temporal output file or exit with error
  TMP_FILE=`mktemp` || \
    error "could not create temporal output file"

  #############################
  # process pom file with awk #
  # and save modified version #
  # in temporal output file   #
  #############################

  awk \
    -F "rpm.release>" \
    -v OFS="rpm.release>" \
    -v BUILD_NUM="$BUILD_NUM" \
    '
      /<properties>/{
        properties=1
      }
      /<\/properties>/{
        properties=0
      }
      properties&&$1~/<$/&&$2~/<\/$/{
        $2=BUILD_NUM"</"
      }
      1
    ' "$POM_FILE" > "$TMP_FILE" || \
    error "processing pom file $POM_FILE with awk failed"

  #########################
  # move modified version #
  # back to original path #
  #########################

  mv -- "$TMP_FILE" "$POM_FILE" || \
    error "could not mv temporal output file $TMP_FILE to pom file $POM_FILE"
}

# Call above function
update_rpm_release_in_pom 11
```

Note that this should work with all versions of `awk` since there are no GNUisms in there.

There might be a way to do this in `sed` and get around the tmpfile stuff by using `sed`'s inplace (`-i`) option, but a) I am not sure how to do this in a safe way in `sed` and b) I do not even know if you run a version of `sed` that supports the `-i` option.

In case you need further help, adjustments and/or explanations, feel free to add a comment.

**Addendum:**

In case you *really* need to do this without any script language, I modified your code and substituted my `awk` code with that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# error function
error(){
 echo -e >&2 "error: $@"
 exit 1
}

update_rpm_release_in_pom()
{
  #################
  # set constants #
  #################

  POM_FILE="./template/iptools/pom.xml"
  USAGE="usage: update_rpm_release_in_pom <build num>"

  #################
  # sanity checks #
  #################

  # argument given?
  [[ $# -eq 1 ]] || \
    error "wrong number of parameters\n$USAGE"

  # pom file exists?
  [[ -e "$POM_FILE" ]] || \
    error "pom file $POM_FILE does not exist"

  # pom file readable?
  [[ -r "$POM_FILE" ]] || \
    error "pom file $POM_FILE is not readable"

  # pom file writeable?
  [[ -w "$POM_FILE" ]] || \
    error "pom file $POM_FILE is not writeable"

  ##################
  # set parameters #
  ##################

  BUILD_NUM=$1

  ###############################
  # create temporal output file #
  # and ensure its removal      #
  ###############################

  # cleanup function
  cleanup(){
    [[ -e "$TMP_FILE" ]] && rm -- "$TMP_FILE"
  }

  # ensure cleanup on exit
  trap 'cleanup' EXIT

  # create temporal output file or exit with error
  TMP_FILE=`mktemp` || \
    error "could not create temporal output file"

  ##############################
  # process pom file with bash #
  # and save modified version  #
  # in temporal output file    #
  ##############################

  BEGIN_PROPERTIES="n"
  while read LINE
  do
    case $BEGIN_PROPERTIES in
      n) # <property> tag not found yet
        [[ "$LINE" == *\<properties\>* ]] && BEGIN_PROPERTIES="y"
        echo "$LINE"
        continue
      ;;
      y) # <property> tag found
        [[ "$LINE" == *\</properties\>* ]] && BEGIN_PROPERTIES="n"
        if [[ "$LINE" == *rpm.release* ]]; then
          # Update value
          echo "${LINE/<rpm\.release>*<\/rpm\.release>/<rpm.release>$BUILD_NUM<\\rpm.release>}"
          continue
        fi
        echo "$LINE"
      ;;
    esac
  done < "$POM_FILE" > "$TMP_FILE" || \
    error "processing pom file $POM_FILE with bash failed"

  #########################
  # move modified version #
  # back to original path #
  #########################

  mv -- "$TMP_FILE" "$POM_FILE" || \
    error "could not mv temporal output file $TMP_FILE to pom file $POM_FILE"
}

# Call above function
update_rpm_release_in_pom 11
```

However, this is not as stable as the above solution.
For example, on my machine this removes the leading whitespace from the pom file.
I do not know whether this is due to some quoting problem or if you'd need to adjust parameters of `read` or `echo`.
Since I would never use such a soultion I will not further investigate on this but maybe this helps you in case you insist on a `bash`-only solution.

Comment: I will try this, thanks! My version of sed supports the "-i" option yes

Comment: I used the first solution, which worked perfectly after i modified the mktemp call that worked for me (in edited code). Thanks!

Comment: I updated the `mktemp` call to not use the `--tmpdir` option without specifying a DIR `value`. I use GNU `mktemp` (`coreutils` 8.20) and this is looks for the `$TMPDIR` environment variable. If this was not set, `/tmp` is used. I guess this is non-standard and failed for you. Does the code work for you as it is now or do you still need to do adjustmnts? I would like my answer to be as portable as possible.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
[[ $LINE =~ ^([^>]+>)([0-9]+)(.*) ]] && printf -v LINE "%s%d%s" \
    "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" \
    $(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1 )) \
    "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

[BASH_REMATCH](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH) is an array set by the `=~` operator to store the values within capturing parentheses.

---

It just updates the line. I would rewrite it completely using my favourite command line xml tool:

```
update_rpm_release_in_pom() {
    local f=pom.xml
    # get the current value
    local current=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/properties/rpm.release' $f)
    local new=$(( current + 1 ))
    # update the xml with the new value and save it
    xmlstarlet ed -u '/properties/rpm.release' -v $new $f > $f.$new &&
      mv $f $f.$current &&
      mv $f.$new $f
}
```

Comment: So how does this fit in my function? Will this update the pom.xml file contents?

Comment: ./test.sh: line 7: xmlstarlet: command not found. Installing the module is not an option. This is WHY I asked for vanilla bash.